# Does weak convergence imply $L^2$-norm convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

> Let $\{f_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of functions in $L^2[0,1]$ converging to $f$ weakly. Does it imply  that $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$-norm?

This question appeared in an exam paper on functional analysis which I failed to solve properly. Any help in this regard will be warmly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Converges weakly in what sense?

Comment: @GBA $f_n \xrightarrow {\text {weakly}} f$ in $L^2[0,1]$ means for any $\varphi \in (L^2[0,1])^*$ we have $\varphi (f_n) \to \varphi (f)$ as $n \to \infty.$

Comment: It is true for $L^{1}$ as I know (proved by Schur). I am not certain but it is not true for any $L^{p}$ when p is not 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. As $X:=L^2[0,1]$ is a separable Hilbert space there exists an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ (this is going to be some trignometric sequence depending on whether your functions are real or complex valued). By Riesz Representation we know for any $f\in X^*$ there exists a fixed $z\in X$ such that $f(x)=\langle x,z\rangle$ for all $x\in X$. As $z=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle e_n,z\rangle e_n$ we must have that $\langle e_n,z\rangle\to 0$. Thus for all $f\in X^*$ we have $f(e_n)\to 0$. However, $\|e_n\|=1$ for every $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Any orthonormal sequence converges weakly to zero but clearly is not norm convergent.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? How do I prove the claims you mentioned?

Comment: Consider $\{e_{n}:=e^{2\pi i n x} \}_{n}$. By Riemann Lebesgue lemma they converge weakly to $0$, but they satisfy $||e_{n}||=c \neq 0$ (c is something like 1 or a integer multiple of $\pi$).

Comment: Orthogonal is not enough for weak convergence to 0. If the sequence is unbounded you can find counterexamples.

Comment: Good point, should be orthonormal.